# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined when creating weather app using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, typeerror

I am trying to create a weather app using REACT and I am following a tutorial as this is one of my first times at this link (https://medium.com/@leizl.samano/how-to-make-a-weather-app-using-react-403c88252deb). I have re-read through the steps several times and keep getting this error, I initially typed out my code, then thought I made a mistake, kept trying to edit to debug.  Since it still wasn't working I copied and pasted directly from the website to see if that fixed it but continue to get the same error, I read through a few forums on here but unsure how to fix it:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
(anonymous function)
src/WeekContainer.js:25
  22 | fetch(weatherURL)
  23 | .then(res => res.json())
  24 | .then(data => {
> 25 |   const dailyData = data.list.filter(reading => reading.dt_txt.includes("18:00:00"))
     | ^  26 |   this.setState({
  27 |     fullData: data.list,
  28 |     dailyData: dailyData
```

The full code is listed below:

```
import React from 'react';
import DayCard from './DayCard.js';
import DegreeToggle from './DegreeToggle.js';
class WeekContainer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    fullData: [],
    dailyData: [],
    degreeType: "fahrenheit"
  }
  updateForecastDegree = event => {
    this.setState({
      degreeType: event.target.value
    }, () => console.log(this.state))
  }
  componentDidMount = () => {
    const weatherURL =
    `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?zip=11102&units=imperial&APPID=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`
    fetch(weatherURL)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      const dailyData = data.list.filter(reading => reading.dt_txt.includes("18:00:00"))
      this.setState({
        fullData: data.list,
        dailyData: dailyData
      }, () => console.log(this.state))
    })
  }
  formatDayCards = () => {
   return this.state.dailyData.map((reading, index) => <DayCard reading={reading} key={index} />)
 }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
      <h1 className="display-1 jumbotron">5-Day Forecast.</h1>
      <h5 className="display-5 text-muted">New York, US</h5>
        <div className="row justify-content-center">
          {this.formatDayCards()}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default WeekContainer;
```

What am I doing wrong here, I have looked over several forum answers for similar errors and most of them reference creating an empty array which does exist in the code above before it tries to filter? The only aspect that I have edited from the original is how the API key is referenced within the code, as I went about it slightly differently than the article suggested, but the error occurs after that, and when I commented out just the filter section it worked without any errors. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you `console.log(data)` and check what are the properties available? Looks like `list` property is not available

Comment: The immediate issue is that, whatever `data` is, it has no defined property of `list`, so when you are doing `data.list` the result is `undefined`. As `undefined` has no property of `.filter` (because it is just `undefined`) you get an error. You probably want to investigate what is in `data` and make sure it looks correct. If not, look upstream to see why you are failing to get the expected response.  If it looks as expected and you just need to handle occasional issues when `.list` is undefined, you can check first that it is defined before you continue w/ filtering. Good luck, happy coding!

Comment: Make sure your API key is being loaded correctly from the .env file as well

Comment: All fixed, thank you so much for your help and suggestions! It was an issue with env file that was causing the bug issue with the API key reference